# POST pdf file in data using requests library python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I have a endpoint which I need to POST data using Rest API.

What I usually do form all key value pair and add that into json.dumps like this

```
requests.post(url=url, auth= auth, data= json.dumps({'to': 'XX','from': 'YY'}))
```

But I have another Endpoint which accept pdf file in the data parameter using POST method

```
requests.post(url=url, auth= auth, data= json.dumps({'file_data', UNKNOWN, 'to': 'XX','from': 'YY'}))
```

I have a document for the endpoint which say I need to pass value for the file_data parameter

> The PDF file(s) to send. Please note valid content types
>   below and ensure this is posted as a file (per RFC1867) (e.g.
>   using an HTML form input type of "file").
>   The file_data should be sent in PDF format with an application/pdf mime type

what I tried to pass in the file_data parameter is

```
requests.post(url=url, auth= auth, data= json.dumps({'file_data', base64.encodestring(content), 'to': 'XX','from': 'YY'}))
```

But response throw error 400 : ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
I am not familier with binary data file in programming language.
and also I dont this below code will work for me as their documentation say "file_data" in POST argument.

```
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

Any example might be helpful to me.

Comment: Sorry Forget to tell about content type which I pass here base64.encodestring(content)
I am not sure what is this format type but printing the content will display something like this:

%PDF-1.2 
1 0 obj
<<
/Title (8bd61eee-1bc2-11e8-8af7-c1896399554e)
/CreationDate (D:20180227133212)
/ModDate (D:20180227133212)
/Producer (GraphicsMagick 1.3.20 2014-08-16 Q8 http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/)
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 3 0 R
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<<
/Type /Pages
/Kids [ 4 0 R ]
/Count 1
>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Parent 3 0 R
/Resources <<
/XObject